# How do i make my wordsearch generator code more effective?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, random

I am trying to make a wordsearch puzzle generator using python and the random library. Basically in a 15x15 grid i choose a random spot and a random orientation to put the word in (horizontal, vertical or diagonal) and i check if it can be placed or else i do the entire thing again. Problem is even though there may be large un-used spots in the grid (especially on the corners) the code cannot place them. Can anyone say how to make my code more effective ?

Here are some outputs explain my problem :
[Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F1Mm.png)
[Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvThp.png)

(https://github.com/MaxKindaNUBa/WordSearch/blob/main/wordgenAlgo.py is the GitHub link to the python file)

Soo for some words the code just gets stuck in an infinite loop as it tried to place the words without overlapping with existing ones. All i could do was keep a maximum cap how many loops the code can go through and telling the code to "give up on that word" when it cant be placed within 500 iterations.... I am trying to make the code focus on those empty spots on the corners of the grid basically.

Is there a way where i let my original code finish its job and add a second level of word-placing where it targets large empty spots on the grid ?
Would help a ton if anyone could guide me.

Answer (score 1):

What if instead of picking a random spot and a direction you selected a random n by n block and searched for words within there?

Good luck! This sounds like an interesting problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).